# In a graph of `N` ternary nodes represented as an adjacency table of delta positions, is it possible to minimize the maximum value on the table?

Tags: graph-theory

Let's define a graph to be a set of `N` nodes, where every node has exactly 3 outgoing edges. Such graph can be represented as a table of adjacency, using delta positions to denote edges. For example, the graph:

[image]

Could be represented as:

```
       0   1   2
A: 0  +1  +2  +1
B: 1  -1  -1  +1
C: 2  +1  -1  -2
D: 3  -1  +0  -0
```

On the first row, we have `+1, +2, +1`, because `A` has edges to `B`, `C`, `B` respectively, which are at `1`, `2`, `1` rows behind `A`, respectively. Similarly, `B`'s first edge is `-1`, because it goes to `A`, which is on the previous row. There are multiple ways to represent the same graph, by rearranging rows. Let's define the weight of a graph under a particular representation as the largest absolute value on the table representing it. Let's define the optimal representation as the one with the smallest weight. Let the heaviest among a set of graphs be the one with the largest optimal weight.

**My question is: given a `N` and the heaviest graph of that size, what is the minimum weight `W(N)` of its optimal representation?**

Obviously, any representation of a graph of size `N` must have a weight of at most `N`. But how small can it get? In particular, I'm interested in answering if, for large graphs (say, size `1000`), we can always find a representation with a low weight (perhaps logarithmic on the size of the graph?).

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by the edge length of an edge? How is this different from the distance between the nodes?

Comment: @Kevin Long, that's what I mean, the `edge_length` of an edge between nodes `A` and `B` is the distance between `A` and `B`. The bigger that distance is, the bigger the `uint` type required to represent that edge, thus my interest. For example, "is an `uint16` enough to represent big graphs if we rearrange its representation in a favorable way"?

Comment: Then why is the edge length of $A_0 \iff C_2$ equal to $2$ if the nodes are one edge apart? Also, $A_0, C_2$ is not an edge in your graph- do you just mean for any pair of ports? I also don't understand why you would associate this value to the ports- the edge length from $A_0$ to $C_2$ is just the distance between $A$ and $C$. Why do we have to mention the ports? This seems to only care about pairs of vertices.

Comment: @KevinLong this was a mistake. Also, you're right, the edge between `A0` and `C2` could be presented as just the distance, for the sake of this question. I'd make the question simpler indeed. It was formulated this way because that's how the original format is, but now I realize I could have discarded that information. Let me try improving it.

Comment: @KevinLong I've edited the question, let me know if it is improved this way.

Comment: I'm guessing we assume connectedness, otherwise you could just give each edge a loop and pair $A$ with $B$, $C$ with $D$, and so on, guaranteeing weight $1$. If you keep ternary, there have to be an even number of vertices, though you could generalize to $k$-regular. If you assume connected, then you have to have weight greater than $1$, and it looks like weight $2$ can be done for any even number of vertices.

Comment: @KevinLong oh, I mean, given **any arbitrary** graph of size `N`, what is the lower bound on its maximum weight? In other words, I'm looking for the worst case. As in, suppose I have a very chaotic graph of size `1000`: can I always rearrange the rows in such a way that I'll be able to represent it with `weight < F(1000)`, for some `F`? Or not, i.e., there are some chaotic graphs of length `1000` for which `weight 1000` is unavoidable no matter how I represent it?

Comment: Oh, I see. You get to label the vertices yourself to try to minimize the weight. I was thinking that you construct a graph with labels to minimize the weight. Your question is more interesting.

Comment: @KevinLong exactly. The more nodes you have, the more chaotic / spaghetti the graph can get, so perhaps we need larger weights for some bad cases. But since each node has only 3 edges, perhaps some clever rearrangements strategies could guarantee lower weights always. But I'm not sure, my intuition isn't helping because there are many ways to rearrange large graphs.

Comment: Just an idea: try looking at the graph formed by taking a length $2n$ cycle, and then adding edges between opposite nodes. The diameter of the graph (maximum distance between vertices) should be $\lceil n/2\rceil$ (I think this is true, though I don't have a proof) which will limit the possible representations.

Comment: @KevinLong I understand the graph you're constructing, but not sure what you mean by "will limit the possible representations".

Comment: I meant the graph in question would have a high weight due to its small diameter. Misha Lavrov's answer should provide more information than my own.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We cannot always find a representation with a low weight.

A graph that's really hard to represent is a graph with small diameter (the value $d$ such that any two vertices are connected by a path of length at most $d$). If you have  an $n$-vertex graph with diameter $d$, then no matter how you label the vertices, there will be a path of length $d$ or less from vertex $1$ to vertex $n$; this means at least one of the edges on that path has a weight of at least $\frac{n-1}{d}$.

It's possible to construct $3$-regular graphs on $n$ vertices with diameter $O(\log n)$. In fact, a random $3$-regular graph is likely to have such a diameter. [This short paper](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/pdf/10.1137/S0895480197330266) gives an explicit construction for $n$-vertex $3$-regular graphs with diameter about $1.413 \log_2 n$.

So we can find many examples of $n$-vertex $3$-regular graphs for which the minimum weight of any representation is $O(\frac{n}{\log n})$.